# PHP replace exact string (with # characters)

Tags: php, replace

What I am trying to do is replace A#, A#m,... with another font-color version like this:

```
preg_replace('/\bA#m\b/','<span style="color:#910202;">A#m</span></a>',$content);
preg_replace('/\bA#\b/','<span style="color:#910202;">A#</span></a>',$content);
```

Unfortunately if A#m is the input it only styles the A# part. Any help? The /\b...\b/ method doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Try passing the result of the first call to preg_replace as an argument to your second call (you have the same argument $content passed to both method calls)

Comment: -1 because you have asked the repeated question after this one and deleted. This is considered to be the abuse of the community on SO.

Comment: Like I've said before, the issue is actually bigger than this. That's why I've made a new question. How can I implement this for every chord: A#maj7 / A#sus2 / A#sus4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular expressions work just fine. The problem is that the second one will also match the results of the first!

If you pass in `A#m`, the first regex will change this to

```
<span style="color:#910202;">A#m</span></a>
```

(which is not a valid HTML fragment by the way; what's that `</a>` doing there?)

This will then be the input to the second regex. That one will see the `A#`, replace it and the end result will be

```
<span style="color:#910202;"><span style="color:#910202;">A#</span></a>m</span></a>
```

Probably not what you expect.

One solution would be to simply consolidate both expressions into one:

```
preg_replace('/\b(A#m?)\b/','<span style="color:#910202;">$1</span></a>',$content);
```

**Update:** If you want to make a regular expression that recognizes many different chords, use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
preg_replace('/\b(A#(maj7|sus2|sus4)?)\b/',
             '<span style="color:#910202;">$1</span>',
             $content);
```

Short explanation of `(A#(maj7|sus2|sus4)?)` so that you can extend it: This regex matches `A#` alone or *optionally* (due to the `?`) followed by *one of* (due to the `|`s) `maj7`, `sus2`, `sus4`. I don't know what all the options are for chords, but it's a good idea to read up on that reference/tutorial I link to. Learning just the basics gives you a lot of power to use.

Comment: Couldn't have explained it better myself.

Comment: The </a> was there by mistake (miscopied). Thank you for the quick answer, will try it right away!

Comment: Hi Jon, I have tried your solution but couldn't make it work for every string (chords). I've posted a more detailed question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260037/php-exact-string-preg-replace-help-needed . Thank you!

Comment: How can I implement this for every chord: A#maj7 / A#sus2 / A#sus4

Answer (score 1):

This simple regex will do.

```
preg_replace('/A#(m?)/','<span style="color:#910202;">A#\\1</span></a>',$content);
```

The main idea here is, if its followed by `m` we are adding `m` at the replace string.

http://ideone.com/iQ6P8